# How to inject env variables with doppler into react with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, environment-variables, doppler

I have recently switched from using `.env` file to a secrets management tool, Doppler, and is trying to inject the variables from Doppler into React, which is built by webpack.

However, simply by running

`doppler run -- webpack serve --config webpack.dev.js`

does not do the trick. What should I do if I want to inject env from Doppler into webpack to build my React app?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question from my comment...since I finally figured it out.

If you are coming from using a .env file in your project - I had a very large one with over 50 lines.

Running from a Unix based IDE You can mount the .env file:
`doppler run --mount .env npm run build`

This wont work on Windows VSCode, so if you are running your build from Windows based IDE command line (like me), you have to download the .env file

`doppler secrets download --no-file --format env > .env`

Best practice would be to delete this unencrypted file after processing!!

and using Docker for a CI build on a config branch you will want to run:

`doppler run --token ${TOKEN NAME} --mount .env npm run build`

Answer (score -1):

I found out about the `EnvironmentPlugin` in `webpack`,

When you run `doppler run -- webpack serve --config webpack.dev.js`, doppler injected the env variables into the runtime and we can pass them with `EnvironmentPlugin` by specifying the key name in the array and pass that into the plugin

```
const { EnvironmentPlugin } = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new EnvironmentPlugin(["SAMPLE_KEY"]),
  ],
};
```

Another approach is to pass an object instead, and this approach allows for default values in case doppler has failed to provide the key

```
const { EnvironmentPlugin } = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new EnvironmentPlugin({"SAMPLE_KEY":"abcde"}),
  ],
};
```

As long as the key specified in either the array or the object matches that in doppler, this should work.

referencing webpack docs [here](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/)

Comment: If I understand this correctly, I need to declare each env variable I have in Doppler in the webpack config file? This seems redundant to why you would use Doppler in the first place? Is there a method for using Dotenv? Where Doppler injects or mounts its data as a .env file into the webpack process?